# O que significa o "::" em C++?

Tags: c++, classes, operadores, sintaxe

Tenho dúvidas sobre o uso dos dois pontos `::`, usado para fazer implementação de classes, `[tipo] [classe]::[método]`. Também é usado, por exemplo, no `std::cout`. O que seria exatamente esses dois pontos duplos e para que eles servem?

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 8):

Este é o [operador de resolução de escopo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_resolution_operator). Ele dá contexto ao que está se referindo, ele desambigua uma possível situação onde pode haver confusão entre dois ou mais membros. Ele é usado em duas situações.

- Para indicar que um membro pertence a uma determinado `namespace` como no exemplo do `std::cout`. `std` é uma `namespace`. É uma família diferente de componentes, então para usar membros de uma família diferente da atual você não pode usar só o nome do membro, tem que usar o sobrenome dele também.
- Indicar a que classe pertence um membro. Isto é necessário quando vai definir os métodos (não quando vai declarar). Sem dizer a que classe ele pertence o compilador não tem como saber o que ele está implementando e isto é uma informação fundamental.

Também é usado para acessar membros que pertencem globalmente à classe e não à instância, Ou seja, para acessar os membros estáticos.

Bom, existe uma forma de não precisar o nome completamente qualificado, mas isto é outro assunto.

Então você já aprendeu essencialmente tudo o que precisava sobre ele.

Exemplo simplificado:

```
namespace exemplo {
    public class classe {
        static int membro = 0;
        int metodo(); //declarou o método dentro da classe
    }
}
int classe::metodo() { //definiu o método já declarado que pertence a "classe"
    return 0;
}

auto x = new exemplo::classe(); //instanciando "classe" que faz parte do "exemplo"
std::cout << x.metodo(); //estou chamando pela instância
std::cout << exemplo::classe::membro; //estou chamando um membro da classe
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Syntax/Namespace.cpp).

Ambos vão imprimir 0.